# Retrieve data from the database and print them in json laravel 4

Tags: json, database, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel someone is kind enough to show me an example of how to take data from a database, and display them in json format, in a php page ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't reveal much about your application so I'm just gonna show you the basics.

If you use [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) you can use something like this to retrieve the data:

```
$users = User::all();
```

Without Eloquent you'd do a thing like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

After you have the data, the easiest way to return it as JSON is to use the `Response` facade:

```
return Response::json($users);
```

It will automatically convert the object to JSON and return it as response.